# Atom Typescript Auto Import

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

[image]

How to `auto-import` missing typescript modules in `atom`?

When I use a new module it does show me an error that it is missing and gives me suggestions to import it, but wondering if there is a plugin which can import it automatically ?

I am using the `atom-typescript` plugin but I don't think it has the auto-import feature.

I tried `typescript-modules-helper` didn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You can click one of those blocks like "Import 'RouterModule' from module "@angular/router"" and it will add the import line for you.

Comment: Do you know if this can be done via a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I want to know if there are keybindings for this too. Would be a nice time saver, as I don't like to use my mouse often.

Comment: so that little window they show is the intentions window. So if you want to have it pop up you can use this and put it in your keymap.cson

'cmd-i': 'intentions:show'

found out the name from this thread/comment https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/782#issuecomment-311165738